# Is it possible to get permanently scarred by the sea?

Tags: world-building

My story takes place in an archipelagus in world X, inhabited by people X.

In the shores of the capital city of that archipelagus, there is a bay of deep, dark waters. It's supposed to be dark and deep enough to feel lovecraftian.

From that bay, people Y simply float up from the darkness, naked, and unconscious in a coma-like state, and are then literally fished with fishing nets and revived by a permanent patrol of glorified elite lifeguards, and are integrated into society X.

Upon being revived, people Y have little or no memory of who they are or where they came from but, those who do, all have the same memory: They came from world Y, and that's all the memory they have, most of the time.

Basically, the darkwater bay is a portal between world X and Y that no one remembers crossing. (There actually is much more to it but it's not exactly relevant to this question)

Most of the story revolves around the relationships between people X and Y, their power dynamics, prejudice, and cultural differences. I will most likely come back here for more questions but my question for today is: How can people Y be visually identified? (Both X and Y are regular humans)

I tought, at first, of some sort of scar from the salt water or sunburns from floating in the sea, or maybe marks from the fishing net (I intend on working on an insult from people X to people Y that compares them to fishes or something), but I'm not sure that's even possible.

How can the experience of floating in the sea (forgot to mention it's a tropical and sunny place) and then being fished by fishing nets physically mark people permanently?

Comment: Hi, Gabriel, and welcome. I believe this question is better suited to the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange, as your question is about how to make a particular part of your world work. Here we deal with writing, not 'laws' of how the fictional world works.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be ok to just recreate the question in that sub?

Comment: You can ask a moderator to migrate the question. I believe you flag your own answer for that.

Comment: I've flagged and requested for migration.

Comment: Gabriel [asked the question separately on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/130999/28) after the suggestions here, which is why we haven't migrated it.

Answer (score 3):

Any kind of contact with coral reefs or shellfish encrusted rocks could cause obvious scarring.  I have scars from slipping on limpet covered rocks.

If you want damage from just floating in the sea then how would you tell that apart from a member of society X that just goes swimming in the sea?